# end-to-end resistance of a truncated cone

Tags: integration, derivatives, physics, electromagnetism

Basically the question is the resistance of the whole truncated cone which has top and bottom coal-flaps with radius $r_1$ and $r_2$. I have the $r(x)$ given by a function. I know that I have to integrate from $r_1$ to $r_2$. The tricky part is that $r(x)$ is given like this: $$r(x) = \left(\sqrt{r_1} + (\sqrt{r_2} – \sqrt{r_1}) \frac{x}{L}\right)^2$$ I have to switch the integral from $dx$ to to $dr$.
I'd like to get $r(x)$. $L$ is the length of the cone. Following is the 
formula to get the resistance.

$$R = \rho \int_0^L \frac{dx}{r^2(x)π}$$

#### update

My problem is described here: https://youtu.be/h7xS1rAqdmM?t=135
Starting from 2:15. The only difference is that my r(x) is given.

Comment: The "^1/2" are square roots, right? Please format your math with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Yes, John, I'm doing the formatting and getting back to you!

Comment: I did format according to MathJax.

Comment: In a truncated cone, the radius increases linearly from the top to the bottom. Your $r(x)$ does nothing of the sort. Are you sure that's the formula for the radius?

Comment: My radius formula is given by the assignment, I know that by default it is (r2-r1)/L * x + r1, but this is the hardness of the questions r(x) is given. I'm struggling with making dx dissapear, I'd like to substitute it, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Show us the farthest you got and exactly where you got stuck. As far as I can see it is just plug in the formula for $r(x)$ and the solution uses the same kind of substitution as the video does. But if we can see all the formulas you tried then it may be more evident what the source of difficulty is.

Comment: So, I'm particularly stuck at the integration part. I can't integrate with respect to **x** (detoned by **dx**) if I have $r^2$ in the denominator which is dependent on **x**.

Comment: Every once in a while you get to integrate $\int dx.$ Every other integral will have _some_ function of $x$ and not just $dx$ in the integral. You seem to be just giving up without even trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $r(x)$ given in your question seems like a square of a linear term in $x$

So, for the sake of simplicity, say $r(x)=(ax+b)^2$

Now the integral calculating the resistance becomes:

$$R=\rho \int_0 ^L \frac{1}{\pi (ax+b)^2} \,dx$$

$\frac{1}{linear^n}$ has an easy indefinite integral

$$R=\frac{\rho}{\pi a} . 
 \left[  \frac{-1}{3(ax+b)^3}  \right]_0^L
 $$

Just plug in the limits to get the answer.